# How to add condition in AssociationField in Symfony EasyAdmin

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I'm building book management system. where each books have many chapters.

When I filter the list chapter by book I want to when I create new chapter the association field book hidden or at least filtered by the current filter (book).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AssociationField** has a method called `setQueryBuilder` which help you modify the query.

In your case, your association field should look like:

```
AssociationField::new('chapters')
            ->setQueryBuilder(function ($queryBuilder) {
                return $queryBuilder->andWhere(''); // your query

            });
```

You could also use a repository and call its method but returning a query builder (and not the result) inside **setQueryBuilder**.

Comment: It should be noted that the alias to use in your WHERE clause (in your example) is 'entity'. And that the thing is a bit buggy still…